# Override Adminhtml Order Create.php file in Enterprise

Tags: magento-1, overrides, admin-order-create

I want to override Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create file. 
For this purpose I am doing below code :

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <sales_order_create>Namepspace_Module_Model_Adminhtml_Create</sales_order_create>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Above code is working in any community version of magento.But In enterprise that is not working. So for solve that I also tried below but not working :

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <sales_order_create>Namepspace_Module_Model_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Help me. Thank you

Comment: Have you cleared cache? also add full code of your config.xml maybe it make sense

Comment: Yes I cleared cache. And nothing different in rest of code.I put this code between <models> </models> tag of config.xml